# Permission denied with nginx and php

Tags: php, permissions, nginx

- I have create under my nginx webdir a `ln -s` (symbolic link) to a directory in my homedir
- I now try to read it from a PHP script but get:

> Warning: opendir(/usr/local/n/test): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /usr/local/n

- I have set no open base dir in `php.ini`
- directory and files are having a group in which the web user is part of
- both nginx and php fpm run under that same user

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you give nginx permission to access you homedir? You can grant all the permissions you want to the files, but if the directory's not changed, it's all for nothing.

Comment: I thought the ln in the Nginx webdir would take care of that... ok ... lets see ... what directive can i use for "an additional dir"? lets check the Nginx docs. Probably a new location part with a specific directive.

Comment: If simply making a symlink (`ln`) point at a file gives you rights on the file, then the entirety of the unix security system would be useless. You have to grant permissions on the target of the link.

Comment: they had to correct right but i now made it different, i just use the user as the web user and that works.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to this was to copy the files. I wasn't able to get nginx to read symbolically linked files.

I've seen recommendations that the files under the main 'public' or 'html' directory can be followed, but this was not the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

I remember there is option in php or nginx(apache) to allow symbolic link, you need to check that. 
you could search google : nginx and php using symbolic link
I couldn't remember that option exactly.